# Don't style sortAppend

Tags: jquery, tablesorter

I am using http://mottie.github.com/tablesorter/docs/index.html to sort table and making use of sortAppend. The problem is that sortAppend columns also gets the css.

Is there a way to not apply the css Asc or Desc to those columns passed on sortAppend?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just bind to the `sortEnd` event and remove the sorted class name ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/eY8uH/93/))

```
$('table').bind('sortEnd', function(e, ts) {
    var sortAppendColumn = ts.config.sortAppend[0][0];
    $(ts.config.headerList).eq(sortAppendColumn).removeClass('tablesorter-headerSortUp tablesorter-headerSortDown');
});​
```

Please be aware that there is a [sortAppend bug](https://github.com/Mottie/tablesorter/issues/115) in the current version which I will have fixed in version 2.4, coming soon.